# Can I click on file dialog using SikuliFireFoxDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sikuli, selenium-firefoxdriver

I understand that WebDriver cannot interact with dialogs, but since Sikuli compares images to interact is it possible to interact with file dialogs using SikuliFireFoxDriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver, it seems to be possible to click on file dialog.

If above doesn't work for you, I would recommend you to go through:

http://romankukla.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-use-sikuli-script-with-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

I never used SikuliDriver but worked on the Sikuli Java API. Coming to your query, Sikuli works on anything visible on the screen. If it is visible then yes you can interact with SikuliDriver.